# How to emulate partial multicolumn (compozite) index in Oracle 11.2?

Tags: oracle, indexing, plsql, oracle11g

Big table

```
record (
    id number primary key,

    city_id number not null,
    organization_id number not null,
    department_id number not null, -- extra context, can be 0

    renew_date date not null -- frequently updated
)
```

Two kind of query are used:

1.

```
WITH cte (city_id, organization_id, -- etc...) AS (
    -- table join routine...
)
SELECT r.*
FROM record r
INNER JOIN cte t ON r.city_id = t.city_id AND r.organization_id = t.organization_id AND r.department_id = 0
WHERE -- some condition on renew_date... whatever
```

2.

```
WITH cte (city_id, organization_id, department_id, -- etc...) AS (
    -- same
)
SELECT r.*
FROM record r
INNER JOIN cte t ON r.city_id = t.city_id AND r.organization_id = t.organization_id AND r.department_id = t.department_id
WHERE -- some condition on renew_date or smth else
```

There are rumors that partial multicolumn (compozite) index can be emulated in Oracle.
https://community.oracle.com/ideas/18213

https://blog.jooq.org/2017/01/18/how-to-emulate-partial-indexes-in-oracle/

Do i need to create a pair of some kind of hash function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_record_index (city_id IN NUMBER, organization_id IN NUMBER, department_id IN NUMBER)
    RETURN NUMBER
    DETERMINISTIC
AS
BEGIN
    IF department_id <> 0 THEN RETURN NULL
    ELSE RETURN no_idea_how_to_compute(city_id, organization_id);
    END IF;
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_record_department_index (city_id IN NUMBER, organization_id IN NUMBER, department_id IN NUMBER)
    RETURN NUMBER
    DETERMINISTIC
AS
BEGIN
    IF department_id = 0 THEN RETURN NULL
    ELSE RETURN no_idea_how_to_compute2(city_id, organization_id, department_id);
    END IF;
END;
```

and create two function based index?

upd:
I need smth like that

```
CREATE INDEX record_main_index       ON record (rayon_id, organization_id) WHERE department_id = 0;

CREATE INDEX record_department_index ON record (rayon_id, organization_id, department_id) WHERE department_id <> 0;
```

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: What would be the composite index you'd like to emulate? And you do not necessarily need to create functions to use function-based indexes in Oracle - those can actually be based on expressions too.

Comment: @Hilarion,
    
    CREATE INDEX record_main_index       ON record (rayon_id, organization_id) WHERE department_id = 0;
    CREATE INDEX record_department_index ON record (rayon_id, organization_id, department_id) WHERE department_id <> 0;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a virtual column to the table and then include that column in an index:

```
ALTER TABLE record ADD zero_dept_id AS (CASE department_id WHEN 0 THEN 0 END);

CREATE INDEX record_paritial_idx ON record (city_id, organization_id, zero_dept_id);
```

On second thought you may be wanting only the single column index below instead of the multi-column index above.

```
CREATE INDEX record_paritial_idx ON record (zero_dept_id);
```

Then in your code instead of using `r.department_id = 0` you would use `r.zero_dept_id = 0` to use the new index.

No guarantees that this will improve your query performance, but you can certainly give it a try.

For a multi column index that truly prunes out all the non zero department_id entries you may need more virtual columns:

```
ALTER TABLE record ADD zero_dept_id AS (CASE department_id WHEN 0 THEN 0 END);
ALTER TABLE record ADD zero_dept_city_id AS (CASE department_id WHEN 0 THEN city_id END);
ALTER TABLE record ADD zero_dept_org_id AS (CASE department_id WHEN 0 THEN organization_id END);

CREATE INDEX record_paritial_idx ON record (zero_dept_city_id, zero_dept_org_id, zero_dept_id);
```

Then in your code make the appropriate substitutions to get this:

```
r.zero_dept_city_id = t.city_id AND r.zero_dept_org_id = t.organization_id AND r.zero_dept_id = 0
```

In the last option above, you could possibly drop the zero_dept_id column since the other two virtual columns will only have values in the index when the department id is zero in which case the index would become this:

```
CREATE INDEX record_paritial_idx ON record (zero_dept_city_id, zero_dept_org_id);
```

and the query predicate would be:

```
r.zero_dept_city_id = t.city_id AND r.zero_dept_org_id = t.organization_id
```

with the `department_id = 0` predicate implied by the zero_dept* virtual columns.